# MongoDB aggregate lookup changes the sort of the array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have array of ID's (references) in MongoDB, like this:

```
subscribers: [
  ObjectId("example1"),
  ObjectId("example2"), 
  ObjectId("example3")
]
```

I query this using MongoDB aggregate with a lookup pipeline:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      let: {
        subscribers: "$subscribers"
      },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$subscribers"] }}},
        { $project: { status: 1, personal_info: 1 }}
      ],
      as: "subscribers"
    }
  },
```

As you can see, I take the origin `subscribers` array key that was stored and convert this to the real data of the current ID's.

However, the problem is that it changes the sort of results, for example, if the results were stored in this order: example1, example2, example3, the new subscribers array will be: example3, example2, example1. This is important, since I need to keep track of subscribers queue.

Is it possible to make the new array the same sort of the origin?

Comment: Do you have `createdAt` field in the subscriber collection? It can help you to `$sort` documents.  Because `$in` clause does not guaranteed the order

Comment: When you say subscriber collection do you mean the users collection which is the foreign collection I aggregate from?